# ¿Cómo puedo aumentar la velocidad a esta consulta MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

**Quisiera saber qué puedo cambiar en esta consulta para que devuelva los resultados más rápido**, actualmente se demora entre 10 a 15 segundos por alumno, ¿Hay alguna forma de aumentar la velocidad?

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_asistencia_alumno_total_semestre`()
BEGIN
    SET @codAlumno = '20192667C';
    SET @codPeriodo = '20202';
    SET @inicio = '2020-11-02';
    SET @final = '2021-03-27';
    
    WITH Base AS (
        SELECT @codPeriodo as periodo
            , 'X' as facultad
            , a.codAlumno_fk as codAlumno
            , CONCAT(a.apePaterno, ' ' , a.apeMaterno, ', ' , a.nombres) as nomAlumno
            , h.codCurso AS codcur
            , h.secCurso AS seccur
            , m.secCurso as secCurso
            , h.idHorarios as idHorarios
            , h.codDocente
            , (SELECT SUM(asistencia_docentes.sp_cantidad_de_dias_por_dayname(sub_h.dia)) 
                FROM oeraae_estandar.horarios sub_h 
                WHERE sub_h.codCurso = h.codCurso 
                    AND sub_h.secCurso LIKE CONCAT('%',m.secCurso,'%') 
                    AND sub_h.perAcademico_fk = @codPeriodo 
                    AND sub_h.estado = 1) as total_clases
            , (with Base as (
                SELECT c.id,aac.estado, 
                    sub_h.codCurso, 
                    sub_h.secCurso, 
                    row_number() over (partition by aac.codAlumno, aac.codClase order by aac.estado asc) NumeroFilaAlumno
                FROM utfim_asistencia_alumnos.clases c 
                INNER JOIN oeraae_estandar.horarios sub_h 
                    ON sub_h.idHorarios = c.codHorario 
                INNER JOIN utfim_asistencia_alumnos.asistencia_alumno_clase aac 
                    ON aac.codClase = c.id WHERE sub_h.codCurso = h.codCurso 
                        AND sub_h.secCurso  LIKE CONCAT('%',m.secCurso,'%') 
                        AND sub_h.perAcademico_fk = @codPeriodo 
                        AND sub_h.estado = 1 
                        AND aac.codAlumno = a.codAlumno_fk 
                        AND aac.estado = 0)
            SELECT COUNT(*) from Base
            WHERE NumeroFilaAlumno = 1) as n_asistencias
            , (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM utfim_asistencia_alumnos.clases c 
                INNER JOIN oeraae_estandar.horarios sub_h 
                    ON sub_h.idHorarios = c.codHorario 
                WHERE sub_h.codCurso = h.codCurso 
                    AND sub_h.secCurso LIKE CONCAT('%',m.secCurso,'%') 
                    AND sub_h.perAcademico_fk = @codPeriodo 
                    AND sub_h.estado = 1) as clases_registradas
        FROM oeraae_estandar.alumnos a 
        LEFT JOIN oeraae_estandar.matricula m 
            ON a.codAlumno_fk = m.codAlumno
        LEFT JOIN oeraae_estandar.horarios h 
            ON m.codCurso = h.codCurso
        WHERE IF(@codAlumno != '', a.codAlumno_fk = @codAlumno, a.codAlumno_fk is not null)
            AND h.perAcademico_fk = @codPeriodo 
            AND m.codPeriodo = @codPeriodo
            AND LOCATE( m.secCurso, h.secCurso ) != 0 
            AND h.estado = 1
        GROUP BY h.codCurso, h.secCurso ORDER BY nomAlumno asc, codcur asc, seccur asc
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT periodo AS PERIODO
        , facultad AS FACULTAD
        , codAlumno AS CODIGO
        , nomAlumno AS NOMBRE_ALUMNO
        , codcur AS CURSO
        , secCurso AS SECCION
        , total_clases AS TOTAL_CLASES
        , n_asistencias AS N_ASIS
        , clases_registradas AS CLA_REGISTRADAS
        , (clases_registradas - n_asistencias) as N_INASIST 
        , concat(round(( (clases_registradas - n_asistencias)/clases_registradas * 100 ),2),'%') as PROCENTAJE_INASIST
        , concat(round(( n_asistencias/clases_registradas * 100 ),2),'%') as PORCENTAJE_ASIST
    FROM Base;
END
```

Comment: Crear una vista, ajustar los índices de las tablas, particionar las tablas, entre otras sugerencias. Sin saber cómo están definidas las tablas, sus índices y el volumen de datos, es imposible decir nada más

Comment: ¿En dónde invocas al procedimiento? Saca un `EXPLAIN PLAN` de la consulta.

Comment: Podrías plantar las estructuras y una serie de datos de prueba y resultados deseados?, de lo contrario difícilmente serán mas que consejos genéricos de rendimiento.

Comment: Voy a diferir con @Alfabravo, procurar no usar un LIKE que empiece por "%" (ya que ignora índices), y no poner consultas en los campos de una consulta, ya que no optimiza la navegación, mejor usar UNION. Y muy probablemente hay mejores formas de resolver algo que un "where row_number() = 1".

Comment: Pues todos estos comentarios sólo resaltan lo incompleta que está la pregunta. Sin ver cómo están armadas las tablas y cómo son los datos, estamos es adivinando. Por eso la voté para cierre.